# Java Stream Object Elements

Tags: java, c#, android, java-stream

I have a code block that needed to convert from `c#` as `java`

```
public List<Student> getListWithSameStudentSet() {
    return(StudentManager.studentList.ToList().FindAll(m =>
        m.listID != this.listID
        m.studentList.Except(this.studentList).Count() == 0)); 
}
```

My attempt as followed:

```
List<UUID> checklist = stream(StudentManager.studentList).select(m -> m.getstudentList()).first();
checklist.removeAll(this.studentList);
return(stream(ApplianceDataManager.signatureList).where(m ->
    m.getListID() != this.listID &&
    checklist.size() == 0)).toList();
```

What I aware was the stream `.first()` is not performing `FindAll`. Is there any options for me to get `FindAll` as well as `.Except`?

Advance Notice: my device using `KitKat` with `API level 19`

Comment: This is not the Java Stream API. Besides that, you should recognize that whether `checklist` is empty or not does not change during the entire operation, so it makes no sense to repeat it for every element (so it’s not even remotely matching the original code’s logic). But what is the logic behind `m.studentList.Except(this.studentList).Count() == 0`? A very inefficient way of saying `this.studentList.containsAll(m.studentList)`?

Comment: @Holger good shout or at least short circuit it `m.studentList.Except(this.studentList).Take(1).Count() == 0` or `!m.studentList.Except(this.studentList).Take(1).Any()`

Answer (score 0):

## Refactoring the C# code.

Although this question is primarily focused on finding the code equivalent of the `C#` version in `Java`, I'd like to point out a few areas which you can improve upon.

Ideally, you'd want to leverage [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/deferred-execution-example) and only execute the LINQ query *when required*.

i.e. attempt to execute the query as late as possible. thus, your method should become:

```
public IEnumerable<Student> GetListWithSameStudentSet() {
    return StudentManager.studentList
                         .Where(m => m.listID != this.listID &&
                            !m.studentList.Except(this.studentList)
                                          .Take(1)//short circuit
                                          .Any()
                         ); 
}
```

Now this means that even if you call this method, nothing is executed at all; instead, it's *only* executed when you enumerate over the returned `IEnumerable` or once you invoke an eager operation on it, in this case, you're interested in converting the `IEnumerable` elements to a List instance.

All, you need to do is at the point you call the method is to do this:

```
var students = GetListWithSameStudentSet().ToList(); // execution begins here
```

## Converting the C# code to Java using the Streams API

What you've currently written is definitely not using the streams API. instead what you want is this:

```
public List<Student> getListWithSameStudentSet() {
     return StudentManager.studentList
                          .filter(m -> m.listId != this.listID &&
                                  this.studentList.containsAll(m.studentList))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

or if you want to return a `Stream<T>` to mimic the return value of `IEnumerable<T>` in the `C#` version then you can do:

```
public Stream<Student> getListWithSameStudentSet() {
         return StudentManager.studentList
                              .filter(m -> m.listId != this.listID &&
                                      this.studentList.containsAll(m.studentList))
                              );
}
```

## Converting the C# code to Java without the Streams API

```
public List<Student> getListWithSameStudentSet() {
       List<Student> accumulator = new ArrayList<>();
       for(Student student : StudentManager.studentList){
           if(student.listId != this.listID &&
                   this.studentList.containsAll(student.studentList)){
                accumulator.add(student);
           }
       }
       return accumulator;
}
```